# How do I split field with comma separrated and I concatenate field1 field 2 [3 word first] in processor nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I split field with comma separrated field 1 field 2 and concatenate field1 field 2 [3 word first]
example
2022-09-05T00:00:10,677 abc.1         ,
after split and concatenate
2022-09-05T00:00:10:677,abc.1,

Comment: Use `UpdateRecord`  processor

Answer (score 0):

You can use UpdateRecord and add a user-defined property something like `/field3` set to `concat( /field1, /field2 )`. You can change `/field3` to be whatever you want the output field name to be, and if you want to remove the other fields you can specify a schema in your Record Writer that only has the field(s) you want, such as:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "nifiRecord",
    "namespace": "org.apache.nifi",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "field3",
        "type": ["string", "null"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: thank you,  if i want concat( /field1, /field2(3col first)
field1 --> 2022-09-05T00:00:10
field2 --> 677 abc.1
expect field3 --> 2022-09-05T00:00:10:677
expect field4 -->  abc.1